# Filter list of lists

Tags: list, haskell, nested-lists

I'm very new with Haskell, only starting to learn it.
I'm using "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" tutorial for start, and saw example of solving "3n+1" problem:

```
chain :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]  
chain 1 = [1]  
chain n  
    | even n =  n:chain (n `div` 2)  
    | odd n  =  n:chain (n*3 + 1)  

numLongChains :: Int  
numLongChains = length (filter isLong (map chain [1..100]))  
    where isLong xs = length xs > 15
```

so, numLongChains counts all chains that longer 15 steps, for all numbers from 1 to 100.

Now, I wanna my own:

```
numLongChains' :: [Int]  
numLongChains' = filter isLong (map chain [1..100])
    where isLong xs = length xs > 15
```

so now, I wanna not to count these chains, but return filtered list with these chains.
But now I get error when compiling:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[a0]'
> Expected type: Int -> Bool
>   Actual type: [a0] -> Bool
> In the first argument of `filter', namely `isLong'
> In the expression: filter isLong (map chain [1 .. 100])
> ```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type signature of `numLongChains` is probably not correct. Depending on what you want to do, one of the following is needed:

- You simply want to count those chains, your function `numLongChains` obviously shall return a number, change the first line to `length $ filter isLong (map chain [1..100])` and the type to `Int`
- You want to return a list of lengths of the long chains. In this case, the type signature is fine, but you need to return a length. I'd suggest you, the calculate the length before filtering and filter on it. The function's body becomes `filter (>15) (map (length . chain) [1..100])`.
- You want to return all chains that are longer than 15 chars. Just change the signature to `[[Int]]` (A list of chains (lists) of `Int`s) and you're fine.

Comment: Thank you! Really its my fault, using [[Int]] solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

FUZxxl is right. You are going to want to change the type signature of your function to `[[Int]]`. As you are filtering a list of lists and only selecting the ones that are sufficiently long, you will have returned a lists of lists.

One note about reading Haskell compile-time debugger/errors. This error may seem strange. It says you had `[a0] -> Bool` but you were expecting `Int -> Bool`. This is because that the type checker assumes that, from the signature of your numLongChains' function, you are going to need a filter function that checks Ints and returns a list of acceptable ones. The only way to filter over a list and get [Int] back is to have a function that takes `Int`s and returns `Bool`s `(Int -> Bool)`. Instead, it sees a function that checks length. Length takes a list, so it guesses that you wrote a function that checks lists. `([a0] -> Bool)`. Sometimes, the checker is not as friendly as you would like it to be but if you look hard enough, you will see that 9 times out of 10, a hard to decipher error is the result of such as assumptions.

Comment: Erik, Thank you too, but all that I understand is that it's too hard for me now :) And about evilness of implicit conversion I knew from imperative languages